# How to Load App Config from Json File in Unity Firebase SDK

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine

I want to create a new Firebase database instance in my Unity project. I have the JSON config file of this new database. I try to load the app options by using the method `AppOptions.LoadFromJsonConfig(string filename)`, but it gives an error like this:

```cs
Failed to parse Firebase config: (1): error: declaration expected. Check the config string passed to App::CreateFromJsonConfig()
```

The code is here:

```cs
AppOptions options = AppOptions.LoadFromJsonConfig("second-database.json");
FirebaseApp app = FirebaseApp.Create(options);
```

In the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/app-options#class_firebase_1_1_app_options_1ad8e05cfc9bba063973859a9142728bd8), it just says that the parameter is the filename.

Tried:

- Moving the file to project main folder or to the same folder of
  script file.
- Path input like `./second-database.json`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have learnt that it is a documentation bug and the parameter of LoadFromJsonConfig() is not the filename instead it is the string content of the json file.